# Xamarin Access myapp.Droid folder

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to use the MessageCenter to deliver a message from an android renderer to a contentview. To do that I need to give the location of where the message is comming from (The Android renderer), so I need to use this code:

```
//Sender
MessagingCenter.Send<DraggableViewRenderer, DraggableView.DraggableView>(this, "EditSelectedText", dragView);


//Subscriber
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyApp.Droid.Renderer.DraggableViewRenderer, DraggableView.DraggableView>(null, "EditSelectedText", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await EditSelectedText(arg);
});
```

But I can't use the path `MyApp.Droid.Renderer.DraggableViewRenderer` because I can't access the droid folder.

How can I fix this?

Comment: just use `object`

Comment: And do I need to add the `null` at the end or something else?

Comment: the first argument to `Subscribe` is the subscriber, so you should pass `this`

Comment: And I added my Sender as well, because I am not allowed to use `this` in the sender. What do I need to put over there?

Comment: the type arguments must match between sender and subscriber.  That's why I suggested using `object`.  Please take the time to read the docs.

Comment: I have read that, so I have updated my code above. The message has been sent, but never received? What am I still doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type arguments must match between sender and subscriber

```
//Sender
MessagingCenter.Send<object, DraggableView.DraggableView>(this, "EditSelectedText", dragView);


//Subscriber
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, DraggableView.DraggableView>(this, "EditSelectedText", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await EditSelectedText(arg);
});
```